# Is there a Catholic “timeline” of Salvation?

Tags: catholicism, soteriology

This may come off as an odd request - but I’m looking for a catholic roadmap of salvation that gives an order to how one comes to salvation and maintain salvation through the sacraments.

This request is in order to give a better explanation to my Protestant friends, especially in relation to baptism and faith. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Wikipedia has a comparison of different denominations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordo_salutis

Comment: @Ken those are Protestant denominations

Comment: @LukeHill Roman Catholic is on the right

Comment: @SupportiveDante ah thank you - I’m on mobile and it only went to Weslyian and I didn’t realize you could scroll :)